# Can we evaluate multiple expressions in single line in Spel Expressions. Just like ExpressionFactory

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-el

The ExpressionFactory must be able to handle the following types of input for the expression parameter:

Multiple expressions using the same delimiter (e.g. `${employee.firstName}${employee.lastName}` or `#{employee.firstName}#{employee.lastName}`).

Can we similarly evaluate multiple expression in java SPEL ?

I tried the following

```java
Expression expressionMulti = parser.parseExpression( "#{#jsonPath(#jsonDataObject,'$.customData.price')}#{#jsonPath(#jsonDataObject,'$.previousResponse')}");
```

got error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [#{#jsonPath(#jsonDataObject,'$.customData.price')}#{#jsonPath(#jsonDataObject,'$.previousResponse')}] @1: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'
```

Also tried out without the delimiter

```java
Expression expressionMulti = parser.parseExpression( "#jsonPath(#jsonDataObject,'$.customData.price')#jsonPath(#jsonDataObject,'$.previousResponse')");
```

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'hash(#)'
```

Comment: Have you tried it...

Comment: @M.Deinum have updated it in question

Comment: what is it you are trying to achieve? If you want to concatenate both results use a + in between.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks  adding + does solve my problem partially.  What I want to achieve is to use the output of the 1st expression in evaluating the 2nd expression. 
For Eg.:- 
Suppose you have N Items in your cart and you collect all the prices using an expression Item.price, 
now is it possible to use the out which will be json Array in my next expression to sum them and find the total 
I know I can use the sum in built function. but for other cases will it be possible to that, 
Or do i need register/set in the context separately?

I am trying to evaluate multiple expression in one go

Comment: You can use a stream and aggregate the results. You can just program java in that. But why use SPeL for that?

Answer (score 0):

SpEL is nothing more than syntax sugar over regular Java. So, you need to start thinking about its definition as you would do that with regular Java code. Therefore consider to rewrite your expression to Java code and then go to SpEL piece by piece.

On the other hand, if your logic is so complex, consider to extract some `static` utility method which would be able to use from SpEL via `T` operator: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-types.

The same `#jsonPath()` is a SpEL function on top of `JsonPathUtils.evaluate()`, which you can use directly in your own `static` method. The implementation indeed can use a `SpelExpressionParser` to evaluate those nested dynamic expressions. And the top expression would just call your static method with those args.